# capturing input from multiple computers

Tags: networking

i would like a program on computer A to be able to track the keyboard input on computer B and computer C through a trace() or print() method.

Not specific on which language, although i am most familiar with flash/processing or php, something like that.

this is for an installation i am doing at work; note that this is similar to a keylogger in function but it will be at work on our network and controlled by me. 
I will have access to all computers involved.

*EDIT - the arduino ethernet shield looks like it might be something that would help in this...? kind of NOOB in this area.

thanks!

Comment: First, provide a language in which you would prefere to work. C should be very well suited to this task. Second, provide a platform. Keylogging is very different on Linux, Windows and Mac. And third, describe the environment in which this is supposed to run. Asking for "I want to do this (abstract), how does I?" Will not attract people to help.